# Synchronization in multiplayer game, (Head shot scenario )

Tags: synchronization, client-server, multiplayer

I'm planning to make a browser based multiplayer game for my final project (BSCS).
here is my problem, I'm confused about Synchronization among client-server-client.
let me explain:
               
 let's suppose client(1) shot client(2) at time t1, and client(2) position was c2. client(1) send this information to server, now here is problem before server process information and update game state, client(2) change his/her position from c2 to c3 (let suppose take cover where client(2) is safe). But when server update game state, client(2) still got shot.
              
 From client(1)'s end,, this shot was right. but from client(2)'s end that was wrong because he/she already has taken cover. 

I hope, I explain my problem. and please help me.